# Changing user role after purchasing a products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

I have a need to build two plans (paid) on my site. If the user buys Gold Plan it should create a user (role) Gold and give him 20% discount on travel packages. If user buys platinum wp should create 'Platinum' user role for that customer. Now I have found the code online but it does not work:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 
    'wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase' );

    function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

    // get order object and items
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    $product_id = 85; // that's a specific product ID

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
                $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

                // Remove role
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

                // Add role
                $user->add_role( 'gold' );
            }

    }

    $product_id = 86; // that's a specific product ID

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

            if( $product_id == $item['product_id'] && $order->user_id ) {
               $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

                // Remove role
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

                // Add role
                $user->add_role( 'platinum' );
            }

    }
```

Now I have put this code in function.php file of a current active (child) theme but when I test it and buy the product wordpress keeps on creating 'customer' user.
Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Your code is outdated and with some mistakes. Try the following, that will change the user role based on purchased product when order is completed *("completed" status)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase', 10, 2 );
function wpglorify_change_role_on_purchase( $order_id, $order ) {
    $gold_product_id      = 85; // specific product ID for "gold" user role
    $platinium_product_id = 86; // specific product ID for "platinium" user role

    if( $user_id = $order->get_customer_id() ) {
        // Get the WP_User Object
        $wp_user = new WP_User( $user_id );

        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

            // For "gold" user role
            if ( $gold_product_id == $item->get_product_id() && $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); // Remove 'customer' user role
                $user->add_role( 'gold' ); // Add 'gold' user role
            }

            // For "platinum" user role
            elseif ( $platinium_product_id == $item->get_product_id() && $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); // Remove 'customer' user role
                $user->add_role( 'platinum' ); // Add 'platinum' user role
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work now.

---

**Update:** As you are using the following code to autocomplete orders:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) { 
        return; 
    } 
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
    $order->update_status( 'completed' ); 
}
```

You can include in it the user role change based on specific products. So try the following code will replace your existing function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) { 
        return; 
    } 

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

    // Only for logged in "customer" user role
    if ( current_user_can( 'customer' ) ) {
        $gold_product_id      = 85; // specific product ID for "gold" user role
        $platinium_product_id = 86; // specific product ID for "platinium" user role


        $user_id = $order->get_customer_id(); // The user Id

        // Get the WP_User Object
        $wp_user = new WP_User( $user_id );

        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

            // For "gold" user role
            if ( $gold_product_id == $item->get_product_id() && $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); // Remove 'customer' user role
                $user->add_role( 'gold' ); // Add 'gold' user role
            }

            // For "platinum" user role
            elseif ( $platinium_product_id == $item->get_product_id() && $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
                $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); // Remove 'customer' user role
                $user->add_role( 'platinum' ); // Add 'platinum' user role
            }
        }
    }
    $order->update_status( 'completed' ); 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). This should also work, merging both functions in one.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the answer. I tried the code but the system still registers the new user as 'customer' and not by the desired roles. I created user roles 'gold' and 'platinum' with 'Members' plugin. What else can go wrong?

Comment: I am using this code to autocomplete orders:                                                             
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}

Comment: @Jessica217 Sorry My fault, there was some mistakes in my code… I have updated my answer and also added a 2nd alternative. Try that, I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately it didn't work for some reason. WP is registering new purchases on Gold and Platinum user roles only as 'customer'

Comment: @Jessica217 I can't do more than that as I can't test it for real.